Error loading gapi when porting chrome extensions to Safari
I have a working chrome extensions which uses firebase as a backend to store data (todo list). Everything works find in Chrome but after I ported the extension to Safari, I am getting the following error(s)
Error loading gapi:
Error: Failed to load gapi script
(anonymous function) — gapiLoader.js:11

I fiddled with permission inside manifest file but to no avail.
Here is my security policy which should work (and works in Chrome browser)
"content_security_policy": {
        "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' https://apis.google.com/js/api.js https://www.gstatic.com https://www.googleapis.com https://securetoken.googleapis.com https://code.jquery.com; object-src 'self'; sandbox allow-scripts allow-popups allow-modals; "
    }

Can someone point me towards where the problem could be? Maybe Safari extension work differently than Chrome?
